# to prove infinity norm is indeed norm

Tags: functional-analysis

to prove infinity norm of a function which is equal to supremum of absolute value of that function, is indeed a norm.

I have a clue to check for the three axioms of norm.
but tell me hoe to proceed

Comment: Which axiom are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 14):

$1$: $\|f\|_\infty=0\iff f(x)=0$
$$
\begin{align}
\sup_x|f(x)|=0
&\implies0\le|f(x)|\le0\\
&\implies f(x)=0
\end{align}
$$
The other direction is self-explanatory.

$2$: $\|af\|_\infty=|a|\|f\|_\infty$
$$
\begin{align}
\|af\|_\infty
&=\sup_x|af(x)|\\
&=|a|\sup_x|f(x)|\\
&=|a|\|f\|_\infty
\end{align}
$$

$3$: $\|f+g\|_\infty\le\|f\|_\infty+\|g\|_\infty$
$$
\begin{align}
\|f+g\|_\infty
&=\sup_{\substack{x,y\\x=y}}|f(x)+g(y)|\\
&\le\sup_{\substack{x,y\\x=y}}|f(x)|+|g(y)|\\
&\le\sup_{x,y}|f(x)|+|g(y)|\\
&=\|f\|_\infty+\|g\|_\infty
\end{align}
$$

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Isn't infinity norm max? Can we use sup for this?

Comment: @70pr4k: infinity norm is the [essential supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum) of the absolute value. In any case, why would that be a problem?